# RELACIONES ENTRE TABLAS MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda con una consulta y me gustaría saber vuestra opinión.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Los usuarios pueden ser de tres tipos: si `usuarios.rol = 2` son alumnos y si `rol = 3` son profesores, para lo que nos interesa.
- `profesores_asignaturas` es una tabla que va a almacenar los users de profesores y los ids de las asignaturas que imparten.
- Cuando el rol del usuario sea alumno, éste va a poder ver las asignaturas en las cuales está matriculado (que estarán en la tabla `asignaturas_alumnos`), y también podrá ver los horarios de las clases y de las tutorías, relacionadas ambas tablas con cada profesor y cada asignatura.

¿Esto se puede hacer así, o me faltan relaciones con la tabla `asignaturas_alumnos`? ¿La consulta se hará con `INNER JOIN`?

Muchas gracias, estoy un poco atascada en este tema...

Comment: Sube parte del código que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

Para conectar los usuarios con sus horarios tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
usuarios.rol = 2
usuarios.user = asignaturas_alumnos.user
asignaturas_alumnos.idAsignatura = asignaturas.idAsignatura
asignaturas.idAsignatura = profesores_asignaturas.idAsignatura
profesores_asignaturas.idAsignatura = horario_clases.idAsignatura
profesores_asignaturas.user = horario_clases.user
```

Esto se podría simplificar con una tabla `clase` que se defina por una `idAsignatura` y un `idProfesor` (`idProfesor` sería un `user`), y si esa tabla almacena el horario, y tenemos otra tabla `usuario_clases` que conecte los usuarios con clases. Entonces sería algo así:

```
usuarios.rol = 2
usuarios.user = usuario_clases.user
usuario_clases.clase_id = clase.clase_id
```

Y ahora ya tienes conectado a un usuario con todas sus clases. Solo tendrías que sacar los horarios.

Para las tutorías sería:

```
usuarios.rol = 2
usuarios.user = usuario_clases.user
usuario_clases.idProfesor = horario_tutorias.user
usuario_clases.idAsignatura = horario_tutorias.idAsignatura
```

Y así tienes conectados los usuarios con las tutorias.

Igual tienes que darle algunas vueltas más para refinarlo un poco, o quizá se me escape algo, pero espero que te ayude.